# How to tidy up postal addresses in an excel sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm using a spreadsheet to process information on people as it comes in, including names, addresses, etc.

The way we receive the addresses allows for them to come in very messily and the addresses themselves vary so much. We also have Eircodes which are seven digits but provide further issues as some people put them in as "XXX XXXX" and others "XXXXXXX" and some only put in half the Eircode to begin with. All this information appears in a single cell with no commas to separate anything.

The addresses come in all over the place, examples would include:

```
12 Example Street Made Up Area Co. Dublin Dublin Dublin 22 D220000

12 Example Street Made Up Area Dublin D 22

12 Example Street Made Up Area Made Up Area Dublin D220000
```

I want to make them look roughly like this:

```
12 Example Street Made Up Area Dublin
```

The County name is different across the addresses but is always included and is always one of the 26 Counties in ROI.

Can anyone help me with a VBA code for this please? I have a few VBAs to sort out other information and I've combined them all to a Master command and a single button on the main page, so I'd like to add it to that.

P.S. I'm having a similar issue with phone number prefixes so I'm hoping the logic here will apply there too.

Comment: I would use PowerQuery for the above.

Comment: If you can provide a rule how to build the result out of our 3 Examples then it would be possible to have a code for that. If you can't make that rule it is not possible. Any code you would write would need such kind of rule. Without a rule your code cannot know which parts of the addresses to keep and which to throw away. • The whole task looks pretty much random and impossible to me.

Comment: @SiobhanC This is a very common problem across the industry. There is no 100% foolproof, or easy way to clean up the information, and it is normally a manual process. There are two main options: 1) implement controls at the input stage, so that the information is presented in a particular uniform format. 2) Manual cleansing.

Comment: This is pretty complex to do with no structure. You could try using an online web service to parse and verify the address and return the address components like with [Smarty Streets](https://smartystreets.com) but that option is probably going to cost you. - I'm no way affiliated with the above was just the result of a quick google search

Comment: Have look here for ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4951039/78522

Comment: **Do not try and fix the data.**  It will be a waste of time and it will not provide anything useful.  Instead work out what data you *need* and focus on that.  It might look neat and give you a great deal of satisfaction to sort the data, but unless you have a very specific need you will never get the data 'correct' because there is no correct.  If you were sending letters (to your example addresses) they would all arrive.  If, for example, you needed to know which counties people were in that is probably something you could split out.  Aim for MVP.  It's probably all you will ever need.

Comment: Been asked before, also look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/42085253/4961700

Comment: An Post (the Irish postal service) and OSi have an address cleansing service for Irish addresses called [GeoAddressFix](https://www.geodirectory.ie/products-services/geoaddressfix) This is **not** a free service so you would need to consider whether this was worth exploring for your particular use case

Comment: Thanks so much for the responses everyone!

I get what you're saying, the problem is too varied.

I saw on one of the links there a way to remove duplicate words or phrases, so I'm going to try that.

Is there a way to tell it basically "Delete everything after the name of the county"? That would go a long way I think, as I have the Eircodes elsewhere.